# Why am I unable to use app.Device.IsPhone in Xamarin UI Tests

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitest

I am running iOS tests which will be ran against iPhones and iPads. The app is slightly different on both devices so I need a way to differentiate which one the tests are being run against. I can see that there is an IDevice.IsPhone or IDevice.IsTablet properties but these are private and I can't access them.

Is there a simple way to find out what device you are using or a way to access the properties on the interface?

```
    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
    }

    public bool DeviceIsiPad()
    {
        var device = app.Device;
        if (device.IsTablet)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of `app`?

Comment: Which nuget package are you using?

Comment: @valdertero I am not using a nuget package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the below. I get a warning telling me that its obsolete and to use Device but it still works:

```
bool isPhone = ((Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp)app).Config.IsPhone;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `IApp.Device.IsPhone` (& `.IsTablet`) properties on the instance variable of `IApp` type that you obtain from `ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp()`.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    iOSApp app;

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ViewIsDisplayed()
    {
        AppResult[] results = null;
        if (app.Device.IsPhone)
        {
            results = app.WaitForElement(c => c.Child("UIView"));
        }
        if (app.Device.IsTablet)
        {
            results = app.WaitForElement(c => c.Child("UIView"));
        }
        app.Screenshot("First screen.");
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Any());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to do that I get the following error over the Device.IsPhone "Xamarin.UITest.IDevice' does not contain a definition for `IsPhone' and no extension method `IsPhone' of type `Xamarin.UITest.IDevice' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: @Teague You need to add to your question how you are obtaining your app variable as it seems you are using the wrong variable.